# Get number value read out of xml to excel spreadsheet with decimal places

Tags: excel, xml, vba

I'm reading in XML files to an excel spreadsheet. I already have the code to import all data I need. The problem is, if the value I read out is a number, which is in this format "3,090" then I get only 3090 in my spreadsheet. Should be 3,090 as in my data.

```
Dim strLimitHigh As String, strLimitLow As String, strValue As String

strLimitLow = xml.SelectSingleNode("/LimitLow").Text
strLimitHigh = xml.SelectSingleNode ("/LimitHigh").Text
strValue = xml.SelectSingleNode ("/Value").Text

ActiveWorksheet.Cells(Rows.Count "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1,0).Resize(1,15).Value = Array(strLimitLow, strLimitHigh, strValue)
```

When step through my code, the mouse over tells that strLimitLow is 3,090 as it's in the xml. But as soon as Excel copies it to the sheet it's displayed as 3090. I need 3,090 with 3 decimal places. Even if it would be 3,000 it needs to have 3 decimals. 
Also "Value" can sometimes be number or it can be text, I need it to be able to import both, if it's text it should be go through to the sheet as text, if it's number get it format 0,000 with correct data and go to sheet then.

Can someone please help? I don't know how to fix this :(

Comment: If you mean than "," should be decimal delimiter as "." you can try change locale settings to corresponding. E.g. Russia, where decimal delimiter is ","

Comment: Try `strLimitLow = Replace(xml.SelectSingleNode("/LimitLow").Text, ",", ".")`

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention, I'm from Germany, it's normal that we use "," as decimal limiter. 
The Replace option works for LimitLow & LimitHigh, thanks, but for the Value it gets me "Error 13 type mismatch" if the Value is text not number

Comment: Yes I figured it was a locale-specific thing.  I'm not sure why it would error if the `value` is text though - on which line do you see that error ?

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, it actually works perfectly, I had still something wrong from a previous try ... Thanks for the quick help, you're a legend!